# Sticky, Shiny, Melting Dash - No Notice

Tags: toyota, camry, dashboard

We purchased a 2007 Toyota Camry from my wife's fathers estate about one year ago. Unfortunately, we did not receive a letter from Toyota regarding the dash recall. We missed the deadline of May 2017. It is now October 2018 and Toyota refuses to make good on the issue. Do we have any recourse?  Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While this is a question concerning autos, it's really a legal question. We don't do legal questions as a rule.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal question and not about Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair as provided in the Help section.

Comment: 3 points: 1) perhaps your father or his estate received the recall notice and did not take up the offer... 2) usually this type of program is time limited... 3) this is not a safety issue, so the requirement is not there to contact all owners / vehicles... You have to contact a lawyer, but you may be better off paying to get the work done ie 10k on a lawyer, 2k for the work (numbers are WAG)